# Wordpress, how to make an "if in category then" inside a loop?

Tags: wordpress

How do I make this conditional work inside a loop? This seems so easy but it does not work.

The relevant part:

```
        <?php if (is_category('Sup-FAQ')) : ?>
        <p>If in cat sup-faq</p>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p>If not then print this</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

The whole loop:

```
<?php
$cats = get_categories();

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'support_post',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $cat->cat_ID,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>

    <h4><?php echo $cat->cat_name ; ?></h4>

    <?php if (is_category('Sup-FAQ')) : ?>
    <p>If in cat sup-faq</p>
    <?php else : ?>
    <p>If not then print this</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <ul>
        <?php
            while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

<?php endif; ?> 
<?php
wp_reset_query() ; 
}
?>
```

The loop takes all posts from the custom post type 'support post' and lists them by category. Now I need a conditional inside that loop that will display some text if a category is met. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From [the `is_category()` documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category): To test if a post *is in* a category use `in_category()`.

On the other hand, in your case you've already got the category in your outer loop. Just check `$cat->name`:

```
<?php  if ($cat->name == 'Sup-FAQ'): ?>
```

Comment: you beat me to it by 3.2 seconds =)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I've must have tried every option except for this one :)